# How can I split a textfile by three empty lines?

Tags: c#

Im trying to split a textfile by three lines. For example, my text:

```
 a
 b
 c



 d
 e
 f
```

So, Im trying to creat a string array like: {"abc","def"};

I tried:

```
  string[] result = Regex.Split(text, "\n\n\n");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create the file or read from it?

Comment: Your resulting array seems to be missing the original "\n" between the letters. Did you mean `{"a\nb\nc","d\ne\nf"}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A newline is typically either `\n` (on Unix-based systems) or `\r\n` (on Windows). You should handle both cases:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, @"(\r?\n){3}");
```

Also, you need to specify your regex pattern as a verbatim string (`@"..."`). Otherwise, your `\r` and `\n` would be treated as escape sequences by the C# compiler, not the regex engine (as you intend).

**Edit**: Dan Verdolino is correct; my original snippet contained a bug in that it used capturing parentheses, which resulted in an extra `"\r\n"` string being returned in the array. This can be resolved by disabling the capturing parentheses using either of the following:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, @"(\r?\n){4}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
// or //
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?:\r?\n){4}");
```

Additionally, the OP appears to want to match three blank lines; thus, the regex should match *four* consecutive newlines, not three.

Comment: The result of this code is `{"a\r\nb\r\nc", "\r\n", "\r\nd\r\ne\r\nf"}` on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Now you have it how I understood the question, although OP's result didn't include the "\r\n" between the letters. His question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky but it should work:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path")
            .Select(x => x == "" ? " " : x.Trim());
var content = string.Concat(lines)
             .Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note that this will also work if there are more than three empty lines between the values.

Comment: This solution removes the new lines between the letters in his test case.

Comment: @DanVerdolino who said new lines are necessary ? this gives the expected output

Comment: I take it back - I think I'm being misled by the question's title about 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Environment.NewLine` as a platform independent new line. `String.Split()` works just fine.

```
string input = String.Format("a{0}b{0}c{0}{0}{0}d{0}e{0}f", Environment.NewLine);
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] { String.Format("{0}{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine) }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

result = `{"a\r\nb\r\nc", "d\r\ne\r\nf"}`